# Find the behaviour of the cumulative conditional function and match it to a known distribution

Tags: limits, conditional-probability, self-learning, cumulative-distribution-functions

The given joint distribution is:
$$
f_{X, Y}(x, y)=\frac{n 2 a^2 x^{n-1}}{y^{n+3}} I_{[0, y]}(x) I_{(a, \infty)}(y), n \in \mathbb{N}
$$
The exercise asks us to find the cumulative distribution of the conditional $X \mid Y=y, y>a$

$$
f_{X \mid Y:}(x \mid y)=\frac{f_{X, Y}(x, y)}{f_Y(y)}
$$

So we need to calculate the marginal distribution of $Y$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f_Y(y) & =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X, Y}(x, y) d x \\
& =\int_0^y y^{-(n+3)} \cdot n 2 a^2 x^{n-1} I_{(a, \infty)}(y) d x \\
& =y^{-(n+3)} n 2 a^2 I_{(a, \infty)}(y) \int_0^y x^{n-1} d x \\
& =\left.y^{-(n+3)} n 2 a^2 I_{(u, \infty)}(y) \frac{x^n}{n}\right|_0 ^y \\
& =y^{-n+3} \cdot y^n 2 a^2 I_{(a, \infty)}(y) \\
& =\frac{2 a^2}{y^3} I_{(a, \infty)}(y)
\end{aligned}
$$
And we can finally
$$
\begin{aligned}
& f_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y)=\frac{n 2 a^2 x^{n-1}}{y^{n+3}} I_{(0, y]}(x) I_{(a, \infty
)}(y) \cdot \frac{y^3}{2 a^2 I_{(a, \infty)}(y)} \\
& =\frac{n x^{n-1}}{y^n} I_{[0, y]}(x), y>a \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
We are allowed to divide by the indicator function because we are in a region where it is equal to 1 only.
Now that we have the distribution function we just need to calculate the cumulative
$$
\begin{aligned}
F_{X \mid Y}(t \mid y) & =\int_0^t \frac{n x^{n-1}}{y^n} d x= \\
& =\frac{n}{y^n} \int_0^t \frac{x^{n-1}}{} d x \text {, se } 0 \leqslant t<y \\
& =\left.\frac{n}{y^n} \frac{1}{n} x^n\right|_0 ^t=\frac{t^n}{y^n}, 0 \leqslant t<y
\end{aligned}
$$
Precisely, with the segments of the real line properly defined, we can build the full cumulative distribution function as:

$$
F_{X \mid Y}(t \mid y)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
0 & \text { se } & t<0 \\
\frac{t^n}{y^n} & \text { se } & 0 \leqslant t \leqslant y \\
1 & \text { se } & t \geqslant y
\end{array}\right.
$$

For $y>a$.

Finally, the exercise asks us to take the limit of $F_{X \mid Y}$ as $n$ goes to infinity and identify what is the resulting distribution. But I can't identify any, leading me to believe I made a mistake somewhere (or the question is ill-posed, which I doubt).

Comment: The limit is $$ \begin{cases} 0, \text{ if } t < y\\ 1, \text{ if } t \ge y \end{cases} $$ which is the CDF of the one-point distribution $\delta_y$: $$ \mathbb{P}(D = y) = 1, D \sim \delta_y$$